# Why variables created with querySelector(All) are empty?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In the Vue `data` object there are the following variables defined:

```
  data: function() {
    return {
      sails: document.querySelectorAll('.sail'),
      sailsGroup: document.getElementsByClassName("sail"),
      nameDisplay: document.querySelector('#name'),
      lines: document.getElementById("lines"),
      texts: document.getElementById("texts")
    }
  },
(...)
```

Then, there is this `showData()` method, in the very same Vue object:

```
showData() {
  console.log(sails);
  console.log(sailsGroup);
  console.log(nameDisplay);
  console.log(lines);
  console.log(texts);
},
(...)
```

When the method above is called from `mounted()` hook, it gives: *ReferenceError: nameDisplay is not defined at VueComponent.showData*. The error appears in case of `nameDisplay` and `sails` variables, so the ones assigned with *document.querySelector(All)* methods. Calling them with *this* only gives empty array/value.

Why is it so? How to define variables to have them accessible?

Comment: Please show your markup

Comment: data is returning an object, and it looks like you're expecting variables called sails, sailsGroup to be defined instead of someObject.sails, someObject.sailsGroup, etc.

Comment: Use `this.nameDisplay` instead of just `nameDisplay`.

Comment: @RoyJ: it gives "null" for nameDisplay and an empty array for sails.

Comment: @AbreQueVoy Are you calling `data()` before the DOM is loaded?

Comment: @Barmar: the DOM should have been loaded when "mounted()" hook gets triggered, right? Besides, all of the DOM elements are defined above the script location in my template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
showData() {
  console.log(sails);
  console.log(sailsGroup);
  console.log(nameDisplay);
  console.log(lines);
  console.log(texts);
},
```

This references variables in some outer scope. But if those are actually attributes you set up in `data`, then you need to use `this.name` instead:

```
showData() {
  console.log(this.sails);
  console.log(this.sailsGroup);
  console.log(this.nameDisplay);
  console.log(this.lines);
  console.log(this.texts);
},
```

Note that if those elements are elements that are inside the Vue component’s template, then it’s unlikely that you will find any elements since the component (and its data) is constructed before the component is actually mounted to the DOM. So the `querySelectorAll` calls run before the component is rendered.

In that case, you should either initialize the data later (once the component has been mounted), or use [component refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs) instead.